# Select Method with ControlParameter defaultvalue property behavior

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I'm using an objectdatasource with my gridview, the ODS's SelectMethod is working but not the way I want, I'm sure it's something to do with the DefaultValue property but I've already tried to set it with no luck. 
here's the code:

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AppointmentsDataSource" runat="server"  
    TypeName="DAL"
    DataObjectTypeName="DatabaseModel.Appointment"
    SelectMethod="getAppointmentsfiltered">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtCal" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" Name="chosenDate" DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

 Public Function getAppointmentsfiltered(chosenDate As DateTime) As IEnumerable(Of Appointment)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(chosenDate) Then
        Return GetAllAppointments()
    Else
        Dim appts = (From a In context.Appointments.Include("Client")
                    Where a.AppointmentDate.Equals(chosenDate)
                    Select a).ToList()
        Return appts
    End If

End Function

Public Function GetAllAppointments() As IEnumerable(Of DatabaseModel.Appointment)

    Dim AllAppointments = (From a In context.Appointments.Include("Client")
                          Order By a.AppointmentDate Descending
                          Select a).ToList()

    Return AllAppointments
End Function
```

my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtCal_TextChanged" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
<img id="caltrigger" alt="Click this icon to display the calendar" src="../Images/calendar-icon.png" width="18" height="20" />
 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCal" PopupButtonID="caltrigger">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

As you can see, I want to see all the appointments in the gridview initially since the value of my date textbox is empty. The filtering works fine.

Any help would be appreciated, and forgive my ignorance but I'm fairly new to asp.net

EDIT: I ended up declaring two ODS in markup and switching at runtime, which takes care of this issue but if anybody can tell me why the above code didn't work i'd appreciate it.